# Split a string in AngularJs 2

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have an object profileObj.details[0].time which is equal to "10AM-4PM"
I want to split this string into **10AM** and **4PM** .

please help to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So use the string function `.split('-')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.split` together with `array destructuring`:

```
const [first, second] = "10AM-4PM".split('-');
console.log(first); // 10am
console.log(second); // 4pm
```